# XCode doesn't display teams other than my own

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, ios-provisioning, apple-id

My Apple ID has been added to another team. I can see this other team in iTunes connect. However, I cannot see it in XCode, under account preferences. I also cannot see it in the Apple Developer Member Center. Therefore, I have no way at all of making provisioning profiles for it.
How do I solve this? Have I missed a step?

Comment: You have resolved this issue?

Comment: @weso It turns out only enterprise teams can do this. I had to get the clients login details. Or get the client to make the provisioning profile then send it to me